# How to run EXE in powershell with parameters, in one line

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I need to run a .exe with parameters, currently this takes two lines. I would like to be able to pass a string as a variable to a function, and only need to do this once.

This is how I am currently doing it, which takes two variables:

```
function Foo{
    $ExeToStart = "C:\Program Files\x\program.exe" 

    Start-Process $ExeToStart -ArgumentList "--arg1","--arg2"
}
```

Is there a way of combining this so that I can just define a variable, "y" and pass it into the function as one line similar to below?

```
$x = "C:\Program Files\x\program.exe -ArgumentList "--arg1","--arg2""

function Foo{
     Start-Process $x
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can achieve what you want.

```
# Create an array of the program and arguments
$x = 'C:\Program Files\x\program.exe','--arg1','--arg2'

# Example with no parameters
Function Foo {
    Start-Process -FilePath $args[0][0] -ArgumentList $args[0][1..$args[0].Count]
}

# Example using parmeters
Function Foo {
    param([string[]]$program)
    $params = @{
        FilePath = $program[0]
    }
    if ($program.Count -gt 1) {
        $params['ArgumentList'] = $program[1..$program.Count]
    }
    Start-Process @Params
}

# Call the function 
Foo $x
```

Comment: Thank you- how would this work however if the .exe did not require parameters, surely this would cause errors if the args were left blank? Not all of the .exe's I am using in my project require params.

Comment: Thank you, what did you mean when you said you didn't think start-process was necessary?

Comment: `Start-Process` is by default asynchronous. Simply calling the EXE directly is a synchronous operation. So it does depend on what you want.

Comment: Ah I see, I mean it'd be nice to call check 3 .exe's at the same time, but I presumed this would be complicated to do. Is there a way of saying in powershell "do this whilst at the same time do this"? I presumed this wasn't possible but my knowledge of coding in general is quite basic.

Comment: It sounds like you want to run background jobs. Take a look at [Start-ThreadJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Thank you, I will.